# creating customize table in PDF file using Rails 3.

Tags: ruby, pdf, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to generate PDF file which should contain the following table using Rails 3.I am able to generate the PDF file but cannot customize this.

> pdftable.html.erb

```
<div class="modal fade" id="payviewdetailsdiv4" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Payment Advice</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="bgcolorwhite">
                    <table class="table">
                      <tr>
                        <th style="width: 50%; text-align:left;">
                        <div class="pull-left"><img src="image/odishalogo.png" border="0" name="odishagovtlogo" style="width:60px; height:60px;"></div>
                        <div class="pull-left" style="padding:14px 0px 0px 10px;">Swargadwar, Puri Municipality <br />
                    Government of Odisha</div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div> 
                        </th>
                        <th style="width:20%;"></th>
                        <th style="width: 30%; text-align:left; vertical-align: top;">Date: 14/03/2015<br />
                    Bill No.: 123654789 </th>       
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            <strong>Vendor Name</strong> : ABC<br>
                            <strong>Address</strong> : BBSR
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            <table style="border: 1px solid #000000; width:100%;">
                                    <tr style="border: 1px solid #000000; background-color:#7878C3; color:#FFF;">
                                        <td style="width:10%; border-right: 1px solid #000000;">Sl. No</td>     
                                        <td style="width:20%; border-right: 1px solid black;">Receipt No</td>       
                                        <td style="width:50%; border-right: 1px solid black;">Item</td>
                                        <td style="width:20%; text-align:right; border-right: 1px solid black;">Amount</td>     
                                   </tr>
                                   <tr style="border: 1px solid black;">
                                        <td style="border-right: 1px solid black;">1</td>
                                        <td style="border-right: 1px solid black;">14/03/2015</td>      
                                        <td style="border-right: 1px solid black;">12121</td>
                                        <td style="text-align:right; border-right: 1px solid black;"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i> 1000</td>      
                                  </tr>
                                   <tr>
                                        <td colspan="2" style="vertical-align: top;"><strong>Note :</strong>Thanks for your business<br />
                                        <strong>Payment Mode :</strong> Cash/Cheque<br />
                                        <strong>Cheque No :</strong> 123456, Bank of India
                                        </td>
                                        <td  style="text-align: right;">Total :<br /> Paid :<br /> Outstanding :<br /> Due Payment :<br /> Gross Total : </td>      
                                        <td style="text-align: right;"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i> 1000<br /><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i> 200<br /><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i> 800<br /><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i> 120<br /><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i> 920</td>        
                                  </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="text-align:center;">
                            <div style="height:70px;">&nbsp;</div><br />
                            <span style="border-top:1px solid #000;">Puri Municipality</span>
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center;">
                            <div style="height:70px;">&nbsp;</div><br />
                            <span style="border-top:1px solid #000;">Paid By</span>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to get the above file format inside my generated PDF file.Please check my other following codes.

> table.html.erb

```
 <table class="table table-bordered">
        <colgroup>
            <col class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
            <col class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
            <col class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
            <col class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
            <col class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
            <col class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th class="text-center">Sl. No</th>
            <th class="text-center">Date</th>
            <th class="text-center">Total Claim</th>
            <th class="text-center">Paid</th>
            <th class="text-center">Outstanding</th>
            <th class="text-center">Payment Advice</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center">1</td>
            <td class="text-center"><%= @add_payment.created_at %></td>
            <td class="text-center"><%= @add_payment.total_claim %></td>
            <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i><%= @add_payment.paid_amount %></td>
            <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i><%= @outstanding %></td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <%= link_to download_pdf_path(:format => 'pdf'),:title => "" ,:class => "btn btn-xs btn-success","data-toggle" => "modal","data-target" => "#payviewdetailsdiv4" do %>
                   <!-- <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#payviewdetailsdiv4"> 

                    </a> -->
                    <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
                    <% end %>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">
                        <i class="fa fa-download"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
```

> controller/payment_controller.rb:

```
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController
require "prawn/table"
require "prawn"
def download_pdf
    @product = Product.all
        respond_to do |format|
          format.pdf do
            pdf = Prawn::Document.new
            table_data = Array.new
            table_data << ["Sl no", "Receipt No","Item","Amount"]
            @product.each do |p|
                table_data << [p.id, p.Receipt_no,p.item,p.Amount]
            end
            pdf.table(table_data, :width => 500, :cell_style => { :inline_format => true })
            send_data pdf.render, filename: 'test.pdf', type: 'application/pdf',:disposition => 'inline'
          end
        end 
end
end
```

I am using two gem i.e - `gem 'prawn', '~> 1.3.0'` and `gem 'prawn-table', '~> 0.2.1'` for generating the PDF file . Here my requirement is i need PDF file but the table format in this file should display as per my first code(i.e.`pdftable.html.erb`).Please help me to add this type of layout using Rails 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wicked_pdf gem for converting html to pdf. It is not possible with prawn.

Gemfile

```
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'

rails generate wicked_pdf
```

payments_controller.rb

```
def download_pdf
  @product = Product.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.pdf{ render pdf: "file_name"}
  end 
end
```

https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf

Replace exe_path in config/initializers/wicked_pdf.rb with the path very wkhtmltopdf is installed and that you can get by following command.

```
which wkhtmltopdf
```

Rename your view file to download_pdf.pdf.erb

Comment: @ user123 : Ok,suppose i added the wicked_pdf gem.Now can you please help me to edit the download_pdf method so that i can convert pdftable.html.erb to pdf file after clicking on that link.

Comment: @ user123 : Ok let me to check this.

Comment: Is it working? Please refresh your page because I have done some more edits

Comment: @ user123 : Your first edit was not working.Let me to check your latest update.

Comment: @ user123 : How can i get the  :exe_path .I run your " which wkhtmltopdf " command but it is throwing the unreconize command error.

Comment: Check that wkhtmltopdf is installed or not by typing command as gem list. Are you running this command in project's folder?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78684/discussion-between-rajat-474-and-user123).

Answer (score 0):

```
  def download_pdf
        @product = Product.all
    end
```

Create a file with name download_pdf.pdf.prawn
In that file you can build the table using prawn gem
http://prawnpdf.org/manual.pdf